# How to sort lines in file by number of words?

Tags: python, file, sortedlist

I've started a python course for beginners.
I have a file with lines:

"I was angry with my friend

I told my wrath my wrath did end

I was angry with my foe

I told it not my wrath did grow"

I need to sort lines by number of words in line and inside each line, the words need to be ordered by the number of letters in them.

The result need to be saved into file

My code:

```py
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file_in, with open('output.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    file_in.write('\n'.join(sorted([' '.join([''.join(sorted(w)) 
    for w in line.split()]) for line in file_out.read().split('\n')], key=len)))
```

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with your code ?

Comment: It looks like you swapped between file_in and file_out.
You write to `file_in` whereas you've opened it in read mode.
Then you read from file_out.

Comment: I'm not against one-liner but here it doesn't help reading your code.

Comment: @0x0fba idk site that our teacher gave us to check code writes an error 'wrong answer, partial solution'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to read from file_out and write to file_in.

```
def lines(filename):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            yield ' '.join(sorted(line.split(), key=len))

with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    print(*sorted(lines('input.txt'), key=lambda x:len(x.split())), sep='\n', file=fout)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! Still have wrong answer.. But as i understand here you sorted lines by the number of words in line but didn't sort words by the number of letters inside each line

Comment: @ddcrunk I misread your question. Answer edited